# Receiving Empty DataFrame for Solved PuLP Optimization Problem

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, pulp

I am dabbling with PuLP (and Python, in general) for the first time to run an optimization problem for a fantasy football game.

My code below runs successfully, but it outputs an empty DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

print('--- (1/4) Defining the problem ---')

# Read csv
raw_data = pd.read_csv('./csv/fantasypros.csv')

# create new columns that has binary numbers if player == a specific position
raw_data["QB"] = (raw_data["Pos. Parent"] == "QB").astype(float)
raw_data["RB"] = (raw_data["Pos. Parent"] == "RB").astype(float)
raw_data["WR"] = (raw_data["Pos. Parent"] == "WR").astype(float)
raw_data["TE"] = (raw_data["Pos. Parent"] == "TE").astype(float)
raw_data["K"] = (raw_data["Pos. Parent"] == "K").astype(float)
raw_data["DST"] = (raw_data["Pos. Parent"] == "DEF").astype(float)
raw_data["DK"] = (raw_data["Pos. Parent"] == "DK").astype(float)
raw_data["salary"] = raw_data["Point Cost"].astype(float)

model = pulp.LpProblem("NFTdraft", pulp.LpMaximize)

total_points = {}
cost = {}
qb = {}
rb = {}
wr = {}
te = {}
k = {}
dst = {}
dk = {}
num_players = {}

vars = []

# i = row index, player = player attributes
for i, player in raw_data.iterrows():
    var_name = 'x' + str(i)  # Create variable name
    decision_var = pulp.LpVariable(var_name, cat='Binary')  # Initialize Variables

    vars.append(decision_var)

    total_points[decision_var] = player["FPTS"]  # Create FPTS Dictionary
    cost[decision_var] = player["salary"]  # Create Cost Dictionary

    # Create Dictionary for Player Types
    qb[decision_var] = player["QB"]
    rb[decision_var] = player["RB"]
    wr[decision_var] = player["WR"]
    te[decision_var] = player["TE"]
    k[decision_var] = player["K"]
    dst[decision_var] = player["DST"]
    dk[decision_var] = player["DK"]
    num_players[decision_var] = 1.0

objective_function = pulp.LpAffineExpression(total_points)
model += objective_function

total_cost = pulp.LpAffineExpression(cost)
model += (total_cost <= 135)

print('--- (2/4) Defining the constraints ---')
QB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(qb)
RB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(rb)
WR_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(wr)
TE_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(te)
K_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(k)
DST_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dst)
DK_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dk)
total_players = pulp.LpAffineExpression(num_players)

model += (QB_constraint >= 1)
model += (QB_constraint <= 2)
model += (RB_constraint <= 8)
model += (WR_constraint <= 8)
model += (TE_constraint <= 8)
model += (K_constraint <= 1)
model += (DST_constraint <= 1)
model += (DK_constraint <= 2)
model += (total_players == 10)

print('--- (3/4) Solving the problem ---')
model.solve()

print('--- (4/4) Formatting the results ---')
raw_data["is_drafted"] = 0.0

for var in model.variables():
    raw_data.iloc[int(var.name[1:]), 10] = var.varValue

my_team = raw_data[raw_data["is_drafted"] == 1.0]
my_team = my_team[["Asset Name", "Player", "Pos. Parent", "Rarity", "Point Cost", "FPTS"]]

print(my_team)
print("Total used amount of salary cap: {}".format(my_team["Point Cost"].sum()))
print("Projected points: {}".format(my_team["FPTS"].sum().round(1)))
print('--- Completed ---')
```

The expected outcome is a lineup of the ten players that the model suggests provide the most expected results, given the constraints.

I'm not sure if this helps, but below is the output in the Python console when I solve the problem and try to format the results.

```
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 15 COLUMNS
At line 35896 RHS
At line 35907 BOUNDS
At line 38668 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 10 rows, 2760 columns and 8324 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Continuous objective value is 193.829 - 0.01 seconds
Cgl0003I 2 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 0 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 2 fixed, 6 tightened bounds, 0 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 1 tightened bounds, 0 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 7 rows, 266 columns (266 integer (58 of which binary)) and 773 elements
Cutoff increment increased from 1e-05 to 0.000999
Cbc0012I Integer solution of -192.1 found by DiveCoefficient after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.05 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 7 rows 266 columns, reduced to 2 rows 3 columns
Cbc0012I Integer solution of -192.574 found by DiveCoefficient after 10 iterations and 0 nodes (0.08 seconds)
Cbc0031I 2 added rows had average density of 7.5
Cbc0013I At root node, 2 cuts changed objective from -193.82941 to -192.574 in 4 passes
Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 3 column cuts (3 active)  in 0.003 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 6 row cuts average 9.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.003 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.002 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 1 row cuts average 7.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.001 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 6 (TwoMirCuts) - 5 row cuts average 8.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective -192.574, took 10 iterations and 0 nodes (0.08 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 60 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from -193.829 to -192.574
Probing was tried 4 times and created 3 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.003 seconds)
Gomory was tried 4 times and created 6 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.003 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 4 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.002 seconds)
Clique was tried 4 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 4 times and created 1 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 4 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.001 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 4 times and created 5 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Result - Optimal solution found
Objective value:                192.57400000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               10
Time (CPU seconds):             0.08
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.12
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.10   (Wallclock seconds):       0.14
--- (4/4) Formatting the results ---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Asset Name, Player, Pos. Parent, Rarity, Point Cost, FPTS]
Index: []
Total used amount of salary cap: 0
Projected points: 0.0
--- Completed ---
```

Thanks in advance for any advice on how to get my optimal 10-player lineup to populate the DataFrame.

***EDIT -*** per the request of @chitown88, here is a link to the [CSV](https://pastebin.com/JyLz0UvV).

Comment: @python_noob5, share/post the fantasypros.csv file and I can help you out.

Comment: @chitown88 thanks for the responses. I'll give your answer a shot. I also added a link to the CSV in the bottom of the post.

Comment: Update: that worked, thanks! 

Another question now that I have results if you don't mind - because of the way the game is set up, there is a potential to have duplicates of a player in my "inventory" but I can only use one of those per lineup. This model spit out a lineup of the best player 6 times... how do I add a constraint that each lineup includes ten unique player names (no duplicates)?

Comment: good question. not sure. I'll try to see if I can work that out now. I'll get back to you in a bit

Comment: I got a solution for you. Create a new post (as this is a new question) and I'll post it up on there for you. Let me know when you post it (can put the link right here)

Comment: @chitown88 I appreciate all the help! I posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923638/include-only-unique-values-in-a-pulp-optimization-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, `vars` is a builtin function, don't use that as a variable.

Secondly, you can simplify the one-hot encoding you do for the binary positions by simply using `panda`'s `.get_dummies()`.

Lastly, it's not assigning the `1.0` value to your `"is_drafted"` column. Try `.loc` instead of `.iloc`. I'd also use the column name as opposed to the index position for `"is_drafted"` too, but that just my preference.

Give this a try. I commented where I made changes. I couldn't really test it with out your specific data. So if it doesn't work, you may need to share your csv file so I could debug:

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

print('--- (1/4) Defining the problem ---')

# Read csv
raw_data = pd.read_csv('./csv/fantasypros.csv')

# create new columns that has binary numbers if player == a specific position
encoded = pd.get_dummies(raw_data['Pos. Parent']) #<-- One-Hote Encoding 
raw_data = raw_data.join(encoded) #<-- joining it to the raw_data table

raw_data["salary"] = raw_data["Point Cost"].astype(float)

model = pulp.LpProblem("NFTdraft", pulp.LpMaximize)

total_points = {}
cost = {}
qb = {}
rb = {}
wr = {}
te = {}
k = {}
dst = {}
dk = {}
num_players = {}

vars_list = []

# i = row index, player = player attributes
for i, player in raw_data.iterrows():
    var_name = 'x' + str(i)  # Create variable name
    decision_var = pulp.LpVariable(var_name, cat='Binary')  # Initialize Variables

    total_points[decision_var] = player["FPTS"]  # Create FPTS Dictionary
    cost[decision_var] = player["salary"]  # Create Cost Dictionary

    # Create Dictionary for Player Types
    qb[decision_var] = player["QB"]
    rb[decision_var] = player["RB"]
    wr[decision_var] = player["WR"]
    te[decision_var] = player["TE"]
    k[decision_var] = player["K"]
    dst[decision_var] = player["DST"]
    dk[decision_var] = player["DK"]
    num_players[decision_var] = 1.0

objective_function = pulp.LpAffineExpression(total_points)
model += objective_function

total_cost = pulp.LpAffineExpression(cost)
model += (total_cost <= 135)

print('--- (2/4) Defining the constraints ---')
QB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(qb)
RB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(rb)
WR_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(wr)
TE_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(te)
K_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(k)
DST_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dst)
DK_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dk)
total_players = pulp.LpAffineExpression(num_players)

model += (QB_constraint >= 1)
model += (QB_constraint <= 2)
model += (RB_constraint <= 8)
model += (WR_constraint <= 8)
model += (TE_constraint <= 8)
model += (K_constraint <= 1)
model += (DST_constraint <= 1)
model += (DK_constraint <= 2)
model += (total_players == 10)

print('--- (3/4) Solving the problem ---')
model.solve()

print('--- (4/4) Formatting the results ---')
raw_data["is_drafted"] = 0.0

for var in model.variables():
    raw_data.loc[int(var.name[1:]), 'is_drafted'] = var.varValue     # <--- CHANGED HERE
    
my_team = raw_data[raw_data["is_drafted"] == 1.0]
my_team = my_team[["Asset Name", "Player", "Pos. Parent", "Rarity", "Point Cost", "FPTS"]]

print(my_team)
print("Total used amount of salary cap: {}".format(my_team["Point Cost"].sum()))
print("Projected points: {}".format(my_team["FPTS"].sum().round(1)))
print('--- Completed ---')
```