# Include Only Unique Values in a PuLP Optimization Solution

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, unique, pulp

This post is a related question that spun off of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915565/receiving-empty-dataframe-for-solved-pulp-optimization-problem?noredirect=1#comment121807817_68915565)

My goal is to generate an optimal fantasy football lineup given a set of constraints. Due to the nature of the fantasy football league, it is possible that I have the same player multiple times in my inventory, although I can only play one instance of that player in my lineup. I have created an optimization problem using PuLP to generate the lineup, but I need to add a constraint to ensure that a player does not appear in that lineup more than once.

Below is my current model. Any suggestions on how to ensure no duplicate players in my solution are appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

print('--- (1/4) Defining the problem ---')

# Read csv
raw_data = pd.read_csv('./csv/fantasypros.csv')

# create new columns that has binary numbers if player == a specific position
encoded = pd.get_dummies(raw_data['Pos. Parent'])  # <-- One-Hote Encoding
raw_data = raw_data.join(encoded)  # <-- joining it to the raw_data table

raw_data["salary"] = raw_data["Point Cost"].astype(float)

model = pulp.LpProblem("NFTdraft", pulp.LpMaximize)

total_points = {}
cost = {}
qb = {}
rb = {}
wr = {}
te = {}
k = {}
dst = {}
dk = {}
num_players = {}

vars_list = []

# i = row index, player = player attributes
for i, player in raw_data.iterrows():
    var_name = 'x' + str(i)  # Create variable name
    decision_var = pulp.LpVariable(var_name, cat='Binary')  # Initialize Variables

    total_points[decision_var] = player["FPTS"]  # Create FPTS Dictionary
    cost[decision_var] = player["salary"]  # Create Cost Dictionary

    # Create Dictionary for Player Types
    qb[decision_var] = player["QB"]
    rb[decision_var] = player["RB"]
    wr[decision_var] = player["WR"]
    te[decision_var] = player["TE"]
    k[decision_var] = player["K"]
    dst[decision_var] = player["DST"]
    dk[decision_var] = player["DK"]
    num_players[decision_var] = 1.0

objective_function = pulp.LpAffineExpression(total_points)
model += objective_function

total_cost = pulp.LpAffineExpression(cost)
model += (total_cost <= 135)

print('--- (2/4) Defining the constraints ---')
QB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(qb)
RB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(rb)
WR_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(wr)
TE_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(te)
K_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(k)
DST_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dst)
DK_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dk)
total_players = pulp.LpAffineExpression(num_players)

model += (QB_constraint >= 1)
model += (QB_constraint <= 2)
model += (RB_constraint <= 8)
model += (WR_constraint <= 8)
model += (TE_constraint <= 8)
model += (K_constraint <= 1)
model += (DST_constraint <= 1)
model += (DK_constraint <= 2)
model += (total_players == 10)

print('--- (3/4) Solving the problem ---')
model.solve()

print('--- (4/4) Formatting the results ---')
raw_data["is_drafted"] = 0.0

for var in model.variables():
    raw_data.loc[int(var.name[1:]), 'is_drafted'] = var.varValue  # <--- CHANGED HERE

my_team = raw_data[raw_data["is_drafted"] == 1.0]
my_team = my_team[["Asset Name", "Player", "Pos. Parent", "Rarity", "Point Cost", "FPTS"]]

print(my_team)
print("Total used amount of salary cap: {}".format(my_team["Point Cost"].sum()))
print("Projected points: {}".format(my_team["FPTS"].sum().round(1)))
print('--- Completed ---')
```

Comment: @chitown88 shot you an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the restriction to only allow single player (from your dataframe of duplicate players) you'll need to setup something similar to the other restrictions). Here we'll just one-hot encode on `"Player"`, then loop through that to create the restriction that you have to have 1 or less of each `"Player"` name.

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

print('--- (1/4) Defining the problem ---')

# Read csv
raw_data = pd.read_csv('./csv/fantasypros.csv').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

# create new columns that has binary numbers if player == a specific position
encoded = pd.get_dummies(raw_data['Pos. Parent']) #<-- One-Hote Encoding 
raw_data = raw_data.join(encoded) #<-- joining it to the raw_data table

# Will be used to create the constraint of not using same player name in lineup
encoded = pd.get_dummies(raw_data['Player']) #<-- One-Hote Encoding 
raw_data = raw_data.join(encoded) #<-- joining it to the raw_data table


raw_data["salary"] = raw_data["Point Cost"].astype(float)

model = pulp.LpProblem("NFTdraft", pulp.LpMaximize)

total_points = {}
cost = {}
qb = {}
rb = {}
wr = {}
te = {}
k = {}
dst = {}
dk = {}
num_players = {}

# Here I created a list of all the possible players in the dataframe
# This is used later to construct the dictionary of players, then
# to add each of those into the model
players_list = list(raw_data['Player'].unique())
players_list.sort()

pLAYER_dict = {}
for player in players_list:
    pLAYER_dict[player] ={}

vars_list = []

# i = row index, player = player attributes
for i, player in raw_data.iterrows():
    #print('Processing row: %s of %s' %((i+1),len(raw_data)))
    var_name = 'x' + str(i)  # Create variable name
    decision_var = pulp.LpVariable(var_name, cat='Binary')  # Initialize Variables

    total_points[decision_var] = player["FPTS"]  # Create FPTS Dictionary
    cost[decision_var] = player["salary"]  # Create Cost Dictionary

    # Create Dictionary for Player Types
    qb[decision_var] = player["QB"]
    rb[decision_var] = player["RB"]
    wr[decision_var] = player["WR"]
    te[decision_var] = player["TE"]
    k[decision_var] = player["K"]
    dst[decision_var] = player["DST"]
    dk[decision_var] = player["DK"]
    num_players[decision_var] = 1.0
    
    # Here is where I store each value for each player name for the player
    for key, v in PLAYER_dict.items():
        PLAYER_dict[key].update({decision_var:player[key]})


objective_function = pulp.LpAffineExpression(total_points)
model += objective_function

total_cost = pulp.LpAffineExpression(cost)
model += (total_cost <= 135)

print('--- (2/4) Defining the constraints ---')
QB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(qb)
RB_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(rb)
WR_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(wr)
TE_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(te)
K_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(k)
DST_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dst)
DK_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(dk)
total_players = pulp.LpAffineExpression(num_players)

model += (QB_constraint >= 1)
model += (QB_constraint <= 2)
model += (RB_constraint <= 8)
model += (WR_constraint <= 8)
model += (TE_constraint <= 8)
model += (K_constraint <= 1)
model += (DST_constraint <= 1)
model += (DK_constraint <= 2)
model += (total_players == 10)

for k1, v1 in PLAYER_dict.items():
    player_constraint = pulp.LpAffineExpression(v1)
    model += (player_constraint <= 1)

print('--- (3/4) Solving the problem ---')
model.solve()

print('--- (4/4) Formatting the results ---')
raw_data["is_drafted"] = 0.0

for var in model.variables():
    raw_data.loc[int(var.name[1:]), 'is_drafted'] = var.varValue     # <--- CHANGED HERE
    
my_team = raw_data[raw_data["is_drafted"] == 1.0]
my_team = my_team[["Asset Name", "Player", "Pos. Parent", "Rarity", "Point Cost", "FPTS"]]

print(my_team)
print("Total used amount of salary cap: {}".format(my_team["Point Cost"].sum()))
print("Projected points: {}".format(my_team["FPTS"].sum().round(1)))
print('--- Completed ---')
```

**Output:**

```
              Asset Name               Player  ... Point Cost    FPTS
59         Arizona WR #1      DeAndre Hopkins  ...         19  20.301
375       Carolina RB #1  Christian McCaffrey  ...         20  26.500
582     Cincinnati WR #3           Tyler Boyd  ...         10  13.000
803         Denver RB #2     Javonte Williams  ...          8  11.100
1011     Green Bay WR #4         Randall Cobb  ...          5   8.800
1170  Indianapolis QB #2          Jacob Eason  ...          5  11.400
1301   Kansas City QB #1   Patrick Mahomes II  ...         20  23.900
1349   Kansas City WR #1          Tyreek Hill  ...         20  21.100
1658     Minnesota RB #1          Dalvin Cook  ...         20  22.500
2729    Washington WR #2        Curtis Samuel  ...          8  11.700

[10 rows x 6 columns]
Total used amount of salary cap: 135
Projected points: 170.3
--- Completed ---
```